# Angular 10 - Remove background color on mat-select

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, background-color

Just take a look to the image:

[image: mat-option]

Basically, I want to change/remove the background color (the gray one) on this mat-option element. I also tried with the browser inspector in order to find the class that has the background-color line, but I couldn't find nothing.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to either:

1. deprecated ng-deep
2. turn off component view encapsulation
3. use a global style

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex {
    background-color: #fff; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex {
   background-color: red;
}
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: You were right, but without deprecated "ng-deep" it wont work on single component, thank you anyway

Comment: Just one note on `ng-deep`: its is marked as deprecated: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep.

Answer (score 1):

Just type in your css style:

```
::ng-deep
  .mat-form-field-type-mat-select:not(.mat-form-field-disabled)
  .mat-form-field-flex {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

here a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pj5rjj-hnmy6q?file=app%2Fsidenav-position-example.css